# Python pyqt5 - Qt Designer different size between qt designer preview and pyuic5 py file

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

Sample code (papinhio-player.ui - papinhio-player.py not available due to huge files >30000 char):

Qt Designer preview mode:
[image]

python papinhio-player.py ui show (also that is the result of pyinstaller):
[image]

So you can see there is size difference between Qt Designer and python.
The exprected result should be the second.

What's wrong and how can i configure dpi (or anything relative) in Qt Designer?

Anyway there is no need to show code for that because there is not a problem code depending...

The qt designer version is 5.15.2

The python version is 3.10.7

The pyqt5 modules after pip freeze are:

```
PyQt5==5.15.7
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.11.0
PyQt5Designer==5.14.1
PyQtWebEngine==5.15.6
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5==5.15.2
```

Comment: Designer is not intended to be a pixel-perfect representation of the final result even in preview mode, since that depends on a combination of a multitude of aspects you can never predict: actual DPI scaling (which might differ for multiple-screen setups), available fonts, system font scaling, installed styles and even different Qt versions. The only (and still not completely reliable) way to get a close-to-perfect result is by using very specific style sheet sizes, ignoring system scaling and embedded fonts. Besides, since you actually get the wanted result, I don't see the need for all that.

Comment: @musicamante Hmm, the ui files are designed on Linux OS, but the screenshots are from Windows 11 Home OS. Is that depended or not?

Comment: That's *incredibly* dependent, obviously. Each system has its own default styles, with Windows/macOS using their own internal styles, and linux using "fusion" or the default installed style. And, as explained, Designer wasn't written to create "pixel-perfect" previews, it's just a reference, similarly to developing your own website and testing on your local browser and then seeing the difference on other people's devices. So, as said, as long as the result *is* acceptable, don't lose your time with trying to fix Designer, as there's no point in doing it.